# Build fails in vs2015 with no errors

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an ASP.NET core 1.0 project I created in Visual Studio 2015 (update 3). If I try to build the project within VS I get the following in my output window and there are no errors in the Error List:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: QuickStartIdentiyServer4, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

However, if I build the project using the dotnet CLI command (`dotnet build`) it builds and runs just fine.

**UPDATE:**
Apparently, .net core does not work properly when running Visual Studio as Admin. You would think everything should work as Admin, I guess not... go figure.

Comment: did you filter your error type in your diagnostic window?

Comment: Try restarting vs2015

Comment: There were no filters set and I did try restarting VS2015. None of that worked, but I did figure it out. I had devenv.exe set to always run as Admin. Apparently, .net core does not work properly when running Visual Studio as Admin. You would think everything should work as Admin, I guess not... go figure.

Answer (score 2):

There are simply too many reasons why this type of thing might happen. The easiest way to diagnose the problem is to change the build output verbosity under options to verbose. This might help put you on the trail:

[image]

With regards to this type of thing happening with .Net Core and ASP Core. I have noticed that the project.json dependencies json fragment is a bit buggy especially if you start renaming projects and changing their file system location.

If you see in the diagnostic below you know there is some dangling reference issue:

```
Done building target "_GetDependencyFragmentFiles" in project "<<?YOUR_CORE_PROJECT?>>.xproj" -- FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not seeing build errors. Go to Error List window and change 'Show Issues generated' box from '**Build + Intellisense**' to '**Build Only**' and try to build again.

[image]

See if this helps.

Comment: That doesn't help. I figured out what the issue was and updated my question.

Comment: @Rabid Just FYI... I always run VS2015 in admin mode for both core and full projects.

Comment: That's interesting because when I double click a net core project VS gives me an error and doesn't load the project. If I double click a net core solution it will load in VS, but will not build (When VS is in Admin mode). Everything works find when not in Admin mode. I wonder if I should create a different issue for this then...